# Magento - “Manage Categories” Stop working when there are too many products under a certain category

Tags: ajax, magento, categories

I have this issue in Magento and wish someone here can help.

In my store, there is a category has more than 3000 products. I upload an image to this category to make it as the feature image. I click on the “Save Category” and the"Please wait...” shows up but the page just hangs at this stage forever.

I checked the firebug console and found actually there was no AJAX return, so I guess the system did not response properly. But when I create a new category with 800 products, and upload an feature image and save, it took 6 seconds to get the AJAX back.

I have also set the PHP memory_limit to 512M and the PHP max_execution_time is 18000s, but no help.

I also tried to find the solution online but not clue.

PS: This problem also happens when I try to reorder categories which have too many products (say 5000 products).

Comment: Try to look into var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log or Apache log. There may be the answer.

Comment: @Jiří Chmiel thanks for reminding me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Found the error in the PHP error log:
PHP Fatal error: parse_str() [function.parse-str]: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.

So just add max_input_vars = (the number you want) to php.ini and save.

Tested on PHP 5.2.17 &  PHP 5.3.6